# Checking number length from message and then use the value in statement

Tags: javascript, numbers

i'm trying to check if message will contain 6 or more numbers in one length.

Example: Hello! My code is 123456.

```
        var x = scope.message._text
    if (x.toString().length >= 6) {
        scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*CODE removed*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown' })
        setTimeout (function () {
        scope.api.deleteMessage (scope.message._chat._id, scope.message._messageId);
        console.log(scope)
      }, 500);
    }
}
```

This code removes all messages with more than 6 length, which is not i want... I tried this to check only for numbers, however it does not work.

```
    let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(scope.message._text);
    if (isnum >= 6) {
        scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, 'CODE removed', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown' })
        setTimeout (function () {
        scope.api.deleteMessage (scope.message._chat._id, scope.message._messageId);
        console.log(scope)
      }, 500);
    }
}
```

How is possible to get only number length from the message? So i can use in the statement...

Any help will be much appreciated! I did not found solution for this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some regex to remove non-digits and check the length preperty of the string.

```js
var message = `Example: Hello! My code is 123456.`;
var code = message.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
console.log(`The code is ${code} and it is ${code.length} digits long.`);
```